# Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'gql_code_builder' from repository layer

Tags: flutter, dart, serialization, graphql

I've created a data_provider package and a repository package. If I run the main.dart in data_provider, everything works fine, and I get my fetched data. But If I want to fetch data from the repository layer I get this error:

```
lib/example/main.dart: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:profile_repository/example/main.dart'.
lib/example/main.dart:1
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'gql_code_builder' in 'package:gql_code_builder/src/serializers/operation_serializer.dart'.
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'gql_code_builder' in 'package:gql_code_builder/src/serializers/default_scalar_serializer.dart'.
: Error: Not found: 'package:gql_code_builder/src/serializers/operation_serializer.dart'
../…/lib/serializers.gql.dart:135
import 'package:gql_code_builder/src/serializers/operation_serializer.dart'
       ^
: Error: Not found: 'package:gql_code_builder/src/serializers/default_scalar_serializer.dart'
../…/lib/schema.schema.gql.dart:7
import 'package:gql_code_builder/src/serializers/default_scalar_serializer.dart'
       ^
: Error: Method not found: 'OperationSerializer'.
../…/lib/serializers.gql.dart:141
  ..add(OperationSerializer())
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Method not found: 'DefaultScalarSerializer'.
../…/lib/schema.schema.gql.dart:1380
  static Serializer<GJSON> get serializer => _i2.DefaultScalarSerializer<GJSON>(
```

main.dart (repository layer)

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print, avoid_void_async, unnecessary_lambdas,

import 'package:data_provider/data_provider.dart';
import 'package:ferry/ferry.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:profile_repository/profile_repository.dart';

void main() async {
  final client = await initClient();
  GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton<Client>(() => client);

  try {
    final profiles = await ProfileRepository().getProfiles();
    print('Profiles: $profiles');
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

profile_repository:

```
import 'package:data_provider/data_provider.dart';

/// Thrown when an error occurs while looking up for profiles.
class ProfilesException implements Exception {}

/// {@template profile_repository}
/// Profiles from different categories fetched
/// {@endtemplate}
class ProfileRepository {
  /// {@macro profile_repository}
  ProfileRepository({ProfileService? profileService})
      : _profileService = profileService ?? ProfileService();

  final ProfileService _profileService;

  /// Returns a list of all club and players profiles.
  ///
  /// Throws a [ProfilesException] if an error occurs.
  Future<List<GGetProfilesData_profiles>?> getProfiles() async {
    try {
      final profiles = await _profileService.getProfiles();
      return profiles;
    } on Exception {
      throw ProfilesException();
    }
  }
}
```

profile_service (data_layer):

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';
import 'package:data_provider/data_provider.dart';
import 'package:ferry/ferry.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

class ProfileService {
  final client = GetIt.I<Client>();

  Future<List<GGetProfilesData_profiles>?> getProfiles() async {
    try {
      final profilesReq = GGetProfilesReq();
      BuiltList<GGetProfilesData_profiles>? result;

      final value = await client.request(profilesReq).first;

      RequestHelper.checkError(value);

      if (value.data != null && value.data!.profiles != null) {
        result = value.data!.profiles;
      }

      return result?.toList();
    } on DataProviderGraphqlErrorException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    } on DataProviderLinkException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    return List.empty();
  }
}
```

main.dart (data_provider, what works!)

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print, avoid_void_async, unnecessary_lambdas,

import 'package:data_provider/data_provider.dart';
import 'package:ferry/ferry.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

void main() async {
  final client = await initClient();
  GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton<Client>(() => client);

  try {
    final profiles = await ProfileService().getProfiles();
    print('Profiles: $profiles');
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Edit: It seems the import implementation doesn't look right. But the file was generated...
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you try putting gql_code_builder in your dependency: section in pubspec.yaml explicitly?

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem.
Do you have found a workaround?
@knaecke putting explicitly the dependency doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. I am using artemis now.

Answer (score 5):

I've found a solution. Not a perfect one but it works.

@knaecke leeds me to the answer.
You can explicitly add gql_code_builder in your "dependency:" section in pubspec.yaml **on your main lib** (not the package which is really using it).

It's ugly and very weird, but well, it works...